# bpy: light animation from grid

Tags: python, animation, light

First, I wanted to recreate this image applying also a animation to that.
 [image]

To start, I create this code.

```
import bpy
import random

# Settings
name = 'PointLightPathMesh' #mesh and object's name
rows = 20
columns = 20
size = 1
gridOffSetx = 9
GridOffSety = 9
layer = 2
numLightPoints = 10

animFrameOffset = 15
animFrameTimes = 8


verts = []
faces = []


def face(column, row):
    """ Create a single face """
    return (column* rows + row,
            (column + 1) * rows + row,
            (column + 1) * rows + 1 + row,
            column * rows + 1 + row)

def vert(column, row):
    """ Create a single vert """
    return (column * size - gridOffSetx, row * size - GridOffSety, 0)

def createGridObj(rows_,columns_):

    # Create Mesh Datablock
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)

    verts = [vert(x, y) for x in range(columns_) for y in range(rows_)]
    faces = [face(x, y) for x in range(columns_ - 1) for y in range(rows_ - 1)]

    mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces) #we can skip edges because of two parameters

    # Create Object and link to scene
    obj_ = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj_)

    #Add to layer 2
    obj_.layers[layer] = True

    return obj_

def createLightPoints(numLightPoints_,allPositions_):
    list = []
    for t in range(0,numLightPoints_):
        light_Obj = bpy.ops.object.lamp_add( type='POINT', radius=1, location=allPositions_[random.randrange(len(allPositions_))])
        list.append(light_Obj)
    return list

def select(obj_):
    # Select the object
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_
    obj_.select = True

def getMeshPointPosition(obj_):
    coords = [(obj_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in obj_.data.vertices]
    return coords

def setKeyFrameLights(light_):#select and set key
    select(light_)
    currentAnimTime = 0
    for t in range(animFrameTimes):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = currentAnimTime * animFrameOffset
        #set position
        findNextPosition(light_)
        bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')
        currentAnimTime += 1

def findNextPosition(obj_):
    currentPosition = obj_.location
    nextposition = [0,0,0]
    #find next
    coords = [(obj_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in obj_.data.vertices] 
    for p in coords:
        if(p == currentPosition): #find current position
            #add or subtract 1 to each axis position
            nextposition = (p[1] - (random.randrange(0,2)-1) * size - gridOffSetx, p[0] - (random.randrange(0,2)-1) * size - GridOffSety, 0)#p[0] => x            
            return nextposition

def getRandomPosition(obj_):
    coords = [(obj_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in obj_.data.vertices]    
    return coords[random.randrange(len(coords))]

grid = createGridObj(rows,columns)
lights = createLightPoints(numLightPoints,getMeshPointPosition(grid))

for light in lights:
    setKeyFrameLights(light)
#end
```

But I get this error
SceneObjects.active expected a Object type, not set

I'm new to a python and I don't know how to fix that.
And also I will be happy if you give some choices about how to recreate that image.

---

I fixed something but I still not getting the result

```
import bpy
import random


name = 'PointLightPathMesh' #mesh and object's name
rows = 20
columns = 20
size = 1
gridOffSetx = 0
GridOffSety = 0
layer = 2
numLightPoints = 10

animFrameOffset = 15
animFrameTimes = 8

verts = []
faces = []

def face(column, row):
    """ Create a single face """
    return (column* rows + row,
            (column + 1) * rows + row,
            (column + 1) * rows + 1 + row,
            column * rows + 1 + row)

def vert(column, row):
    """ Create a single vert """
    return (column * size - gridOffSetx, row * size - GridOffSety, 0)

def createGridObj(rows_,columns_):

# Create Mesh Datablock
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)

verts = [vert(x, y) for x in range(columns_) for y in range(rows_)]
faces = [face(x, y) for x in range(columns_ - 1) for y in range(rows_ - 1)]

mesh.from_pydata(verts, [], faces) #we can skip edges because of two parameters

# Create Object and link to scene
obj_ = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj_)

#Add to layer 2
obj_.layers[layer] = True

return obj_


def createLightPoints(numLightPoints_,allPositions_):
    list = []
    for t in range(0,numLightPoints_):
        # Create new lamp datablock
        lamp_data = bpy.data.lamps.new(name="lamp_"+str(t), type='POINT')

    # Create new object with our lamp datablock
    light_Obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="lamp_"+str(t), object_data=lamp_data)

    # Link lamp object to the scene so it'll appear in this scene
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(light_Obj)

    # Place lamp to a specified location
    light_Obj.location = allPositions_[random.randrange(len(allPositions_))]

    #add to a list
    list.append(light_Obj)
    print(str(light_Obj)+"Added to a list")
return list


def select(obj_):
    # Select the object
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_
    obj_.select = True

def getMeshPointPosition(obj_):
    coords = [(obj_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in obj_.data.vertices]
    return coords

def setKeyFrameLights(light_,grid_):
    print("Setting key frame of "+str(light_))
    #bpy.ops.object.select_name(name=bpy.context.active_object.name)
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = light_
    light_.select = True
    currentAnimTime = 0
    for t in range(animFrameTimes):
        bpy.context.scene.frame_current = currentAnimTime * animFrameOffset
        #set position
        light_.location = findNextPosition(light_,grid_)
        bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')
        currentAnimTime += 1

def findNextPosition(light_, baseGrid_):
    print("finding next position...")
    currentPosition = light_.location
    nextposition = [0,0,0]
    #find next
    coords = [(baseGrid_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in baseGrid_.data.vertices]
    #nextposition = [random.randrange(0,10), p[0] - (random.randrange(0,2)-1) * size - GridOffSety, 0]
    """"""
    for p in coords:
        if(p == currentPosition): #find current position
            print("Compared!")
            randNum_x =random.randrange(0,2)
            randNum_y = random.randrange(0,2) 
            #add or subtract 1 to each axis position
            if(p[0] + (randNum_x - 1) < 0):#if is out of grid
                randNum_x = random.randrange(0,1)
            else:
                randNum_x -= 1
            if(p[1] + (randNum_y - 1) < 0):
                randNum_y = random.randrange(0,1)
            else:
                randNum_y -= 1
            nextposition = [p[0] + (randNum_x) * size - gridOffSetx, p[1] + (randNum_y) * size - GridOffSety, 0]#p[0] => x

            print("Current position"+str(p)+"next position"+str(nextposition))
            return nextposition
    print(str(p)+","+str(currentPosition)+"?")
    return (0,0,20)
    """
    Note: if this function found next position the next time is 
    called of same object the current position will be the same
    """

def colinearVectors(A,B):
    if(int(A[0]) == int(B[0]) and int(A[1]) == int(B[1]) and int(A[2]) == int(B[2])):
        return True
    else:
        return False 

def getRandomPosition(obj_):
    coords = [(obj_.matrix_world * v.co) for v in obj_.data.vertices]

    return coords[random.randrange(len(coords))]

grid = createGridObj(rows,columns)
lights = createLightPoints(numLightPoints,getMeshPointPosition(grid))

for light in lights:
    setKeyFrameLights(light,grid)
print("End")
```

Comment: Operators return a set.  `lightObj = bpy.ops.object.lamp_add()` is your issue.  Needs to be `lightObj = context.object` after the operator call, or by using API methods as you have  for grid mesh objects.